# Count of selected items in each outer list

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a List where each element is a List of Integers.  I want to develop LINQ to count the number of integers which are == to 0 in each list.

So defining my Lists

```
 var prisoners = new List<List<int>>(n);
 for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
 {

     int[] l = new int[n];
     prisoners.Add(new List<int>());
     prisoners[c] = l.ToList<int>();

  }
```

so I made a List that contains n lists of n integers, all zero - what I am interested in is the count of zeroes in each list, and specifically the minimum of that count, which until I work on the lists is n at the outset.

I came up with

```
var q = (from arr in prisoners from int tally in arr 
                        where tally == 0 
                        group arr by arr into grp select grp.Count()).Min();
```

now the problem there seems to be that when a list has no zeroes in it at all, it leaves the query, and I do not get the answer zero.  At first I do get the answer 'n' (when they are all zero) - once a list has no zeroes in it, I do not get the answer zero for the MINIMUM count of zeroes.

How could I find the minimum count of zeroes in any of the Lists contained in the Lists?  (which will eventually be zero).  I need to make it so that all lists go into the grouping, then I count how many zeroes there are - but I don't know how to do it.

EXAMPLE

```
int n = 3;
var prisoners = new List<List<int>>(n);
for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
{

    int[] l = new int[n];
    prisoners.Add(new List<int>());
    prisoners[c] = l.ToList<int>();

}

//return 3 below - that is correct at this point
var q = (from arr in prisoners from int tally in arr where tally == 0 group arr by arr into grp select grp.Count()).Min();

prisoners[1] = (new int[] { 1, 1, 1 }).ToList();
prisoners[2] = (new int[] { 1, 1, 0 }).ToList();

//so now one of the arrays has zero zeroes in it, but I get the answer 1 - zero was wanted, that is to say 
//element 1 has a zero count of zero

q = (from arr in prisoners from int tally in arr where tally == 0 group arr by arr into grp select grp.Count()).Min();
```

Comment: Can you show some example input and expected output?

Comment: your query is working as expected - it exits because you are filtering it on `==0`  in the first place and then counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to group:

```
var q = prisoners.Min(arr=>arr.Count(tally=>tally==0));
```

As a query expression:

```
var q = (from arr in prisoners select arr.Count(tally=>tally==0)).Min();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are filtering out the inner list if it has no zeros and thus you don't get 0 as the correct minimum.  To fix that you can do the following.

```
var q = prisoners.Min(row => row.Count(x => x == 0));
```

This will work as long as `prisoners` is not empty.  In that case it would throw an exception.  You could do the following if you wanted the result to be 0 in that case as well.

```
var q = prisoners.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(row => row?.Count(x => x == 0)) ?? 0;
```

Or the following if you don't have C# 6

```
var q = prisoners.Any() ? prisoners.Min(row => row.Count(x => x == 0)) : 0;
```